# Wordpress Website loads without www except when linked from elsewhere i.e, from google search

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wwwroot

I built a site for a company in Wordpress, www.public-admin.co.uk  When you type in the url WITH or WITHOUT the www directly into the address bar, the site loads fine - however, if you are linked to the site without the www which is how its set up in a google search, the site will not redirect and just remains blank.

The A records seem to be in place ok (otherwise the //public-admin version wouldn't load at all), although the hosting company tells me there needs to be edits to my htaccess file:

I can see in some other threads people have added some redirect info to the htaccess file, but not sure if i'm defo on the right track here.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php .php5
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]


# BEGIN Hide console URL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^public-admin.co.uk/public-admin-tools/?$ /wp-login.php?CJfSYnpL67maGMJHZr5h [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteRule ^public-admin.co.uk/public-admin-tools/?$ /wp-login.php?CJfSYnpL67maGMJHZr5h&redirect_to=/wp-admin/ [R,L]

RewriteRule ^public-admin.co.uk/public-admin-tools/?$ /wp-admin/?CJfSYnpL67maGMJHZr5h [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)admin-ajax\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)public-admin.co.uk/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)public-admin.co.uk/wp-login\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)public-admin.co.uk/public-admin-tools
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^CJfSYnpL67maGMJHZr5h
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=logout
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=postpass
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteRule ^.*wp-admin/?|^.*wp-login\.php /not_found [R,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^loggedout=true
RewriteRule ^.*$ /wp-login.php?CJfSYnpL67maGMJHZr5h [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END Hide console URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be a potentially corrupted htaccess file - inside wordpress i just needed to generate a new one inside the permalinks tab and this solved the issue.

This video is where I found the instructions FWIW.

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-fix-the-500-internal-server-error-on-your-wordpress-website

THank you